# How to find class inside nested div using BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

i'm working on web crawler right now, and it seems that I couldn't get the class that is inside div from a particular website. Below is my code. I use BeautifulSoup in Python3

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

response = requests.get('https://e27.co/startup/flipkart').text
soup = bs(response, 'html.parser')
content_div = soup.findAll('h1',class_ = 'profile-startup')
print(content_div)
```

I want to extract the text inside the h1 that has class "profile-startup". the above code returns nothing. can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website is populating data using Javascript. If you take a look at the contents in `response` you will see that there is no `h1`. You have to see if they have an API you can use to retrieve the information you need or consider using a browser automation technology like Selenium: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#introduction

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try using Selenium!